# Performance impact of using NetworkTopology with 3 node cassandra cluster in One Datacenter

Tags: cassandra, replication, database-performance, consistency

We are using 3 node Cassandra cluster in one data center.

For our keyspaces as suggested in best practices we are using NetworkTopology for replication strategy using the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.

For Read/Write consistency we are using as QUORUM.

In majority of cases when users use NetworkTopology as replication strategy they might have multiple DataCenters configured.

In our case we have only one DataCenter,

A)  With that using the NetworkTopology as replication strategy will it cause any performance impact ?

B)  As we are using QUORUM as Read/Write consistency which is considering multiple DataCenters, does QUORUM consistency have any performance impact ? is it OK to continue using QUORUM consistency considering future expansions of data centers ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no real performance difference between `NetworkTopologyStrategy` & `SimpleStrategy`. But it will be simpler to expand to another DC if you already use `NetworkTopologyStrategy`.

Regarding the `QUORUM` - you really need to decide if you want it.  In multi-DC setup the `QUORUM` will be calculated from all nodes in the cluster. If you don't need it, then you can use `LOCAL_QUORUM` that will take into account machines in "local" DC